# When send data from activity to broadcast receiver, app crashes on startActivity

Tags: android

I created Button and EditText in MainActivity to send entered number from MainActivity to Broadcast receiver. But when I press the send button the app crashes on startActivity. But normally it works without using startActivity. I enter the number inside the broadcast receiver so I am not use startActivity app not crash.

This is activity code:

```
package com.example.myapplication;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
EditText Ed;
Button btn;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Ed=findViewById(R.id.number);
    btn=findViewById(R.id.send);

    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
          Intent i=new Intent(MainActivity.this,GelenSms.class);
          Bundle b=new Bundle();
          b.putString("data",Ed.getText().toString());
          i.putExtras(b);
         startActivity(i);

        }
    });
            }
}
```

This is Broadcast receiver code:

```
package com.example.myapplication;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.telephony.PhoneNumberUtils;
import android.telephony.SmsMessage;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;



public class GelenSms extends BroadcastReceiver {


static final String SMS_RECEIVED ="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED";

@Override

public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
  String number=intent.getStringExtra("data");
    if (intent.getAction().equals(SMS_RECEIVED)) {
        Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
        if (bundle != null) {
            // get sms objects
            Object[] pdus = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
            if (pdus.length == 0) {
                return;
            }
            // large message might be broken into many
            SmsMessage[] messages = new SmsMessage[pdus.length];
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            for (int i = 0; i < pdus.length; i++) {
                messages[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdus[i]);
                sb.append(messages[i].getMessageBody());
            }
            String sender = messages[0].getOriginatingAddress();
            String message = sb.toString();
            // apply sms filter
            if (PhoneNumberUtils.compare(number, sender)) {

            Toast.makeText(context,"message:"+message+"from:"+sender,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        }
    }
```

}}

Manifest xml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.myapplication">
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS"/>
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity >

    <receiver android:name=".GelenSms"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter android:priority="99999" >
            <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
</application>
```

xlm code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<Button
    android:id="@+id/send"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Button"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/number"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    android:text="Name"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.362" />
 </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Logcat error:

```
2019-03-12 14:44:24.187 8304-8304/com.example.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.myapplication, PID: 8304
android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.example.myapplication/com.example.myapplication.GelenSms}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
    at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1805)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1523)
    at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4225)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:767)
    at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4183)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:754)
    at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4522)
    at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4490)
    at com.example.myapplication.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:27)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5637)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22429)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using the method startActivity() when you click on the button with the intent: `Intent(MainActivity.this,GelenSms.class);` 
So basically, you are supposed to go to the activiy GelenSms...which is in your case not an activity but a BroadcastReceiver. 
So, either you create the activity GelenSms and you declare it in your manifest or instead of startActivity(), you send a broadcast using the method sendBroadcast().
Look at this link: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/broadcasts

Comment: I tried sendBroadcast() instead of startActivity() but again app crashes.I think the problem is about logcat which erıror is" have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?"

Comment: This error is because with startActivity(i); you are supposed to go from MainActivity activity to GelenSms activity. However, in your case, there is no GelenSms activity. GelenSms is a BroadcastReceiver. And the only way to "trigger" a broadcastReceiver is to use the method  sendBroadcast().
What error do you get when you use this method?

Comment: Now the error is change whis is"Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.lang.String.equalsIgnoreCase(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference"

Comment: I used like you sad SendBroadcast()

Comment: Which code you want.receiver , logacat error or mainactivty

Comment: The code shere you are using the method sendBroadcast()

Answer (score 0):

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
EditText Ed;
Button btn;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Ed=findViewById(R.id.number);
    btn=findViewById(R.id.send);

    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
     Intent intent= new Intent(MainActivity.this,GelenSms.class);
     intent.putExtra("data",Ed.getText().toString());
     sendBroadcast(intent);

        }
    });
            }
```

}